# Possibility of Unboundedness in Least Squares Minimization

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, convex-analysis, regression, convex-optimization

*Suppose we have the quadratic minimization problem 
\begin{equation}
\min_x \frac{1}{2} x^TPx + q^Tx +r
\end{equation}
We know that when $P$ is  symmetric positive semi-definite, but the optimality condition $Px=-q$ does not have a solution, the quadratic problem above is unbounded below.* (Boyd, page 458)

**Now, the question is can unboundedness happen in least-squares minimization (which is clearly a quadratic minimization )? 
\begin{equation}
\min_w  \|Xw-y\|_2^2
\end{equation}
What is the interpretation then? (I have never encountered an unbounded least squares.)**

Comment: Does $X$ have to have full rank? if not than unboundedness can definetely occur(like $X$ can be zero matrix and $w$ whatever)

Comment: Probably I'm misunderstanding the question, but the $2$-norm is always non-negative, as is its square, so the term you have written down is bounded below by zero.

Comment: Gerry, I see your point and it is right. But this implies $X^TX w= X^Ty$ always have some solution, which I do not get why. Why is $X^Ty$ in column span of $X^TX$ for any $X$ and $y$?

Comment: I think I now got why. Perhaps because $X^Ty$ is in column span of $X^T$ and column span of $X^T$ and $X^TX$ are the same for any $X$.

Comment: @tom, your example does not work. Setting $X$ to zero gives $yy^T$ for any $W$.

Comment: If don't see why $X^TXw = X^Ty$ has always solution. Use SVD and it should be seen easily. Plus I thought that with unboundedness you meant unboundedness of of solution $w$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user Gerry Myerson has pointed out in comments, the least squares is bounded below by zero, thus its not unbounded. To see this, it is enough to expand the squared 2-norm term
\begin{align}
  \|Xw-y\|_2^2&=(Xw-y)^T(Xw-y) \\
&=w^T(X^TX)w-2y^TXw+y^Ty \\
&=w^T(X^TX)w-2(X^Ty)^Tw+y^Ty
\end{align}
Thus in this case, $P=X^TX$ and $q=X^Ty$ (neglecting the constant for the moment). Thus $q$ always lies in the range-space of $P$ and also $P$ is positive-definite or semi-definite (depending on rank of $X$).